SCR not latching when triggered
I am attempting to design a circuit to discharge an electrolytic capacitor through a bleeder resistor when someone breaks the line of sight between an IR emitter and phototransistor as a safety precaution. The circuit as of now can be seen in the diagram below, keeping in mind that the 45V+ will be mechanically disconnected leaving the capacitor charged at most times.

However, when I actually put everything together the SCR appears to act more like a BJT and immediately stops current from flowing after the line of sight is restored between the emitter and phototransistor. I am measuring ~35mA for the gate current when activated, which should be more than enough to fully trigger the gate of the CLA50E1200HB SCR (datasheet).
I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could help with resolving this and/or direct me to some resources to better understand the theory behind SCRs.

You must have a mistake in how you have drawn the circuit. This has no chance of working. Q7:C and Q7:B need a resistor between them. At the very least. And why is that a mistake you ask? Because had you actually assembled the circuit with the mistake, it would not react to light at all. Not unless the 5V supply was weak.

As-drawn, Q10 will try to short out the 5Ve supply when its activated, and Q7 will always be on no matter what.

Apart from everything else the other posters have commented on R23 should be in the anode circuit of the SCR not in the cathode.

@poxyping Please write a specific question on where you are stuck.

As well as the other comments, it's bad juju to pull negative current from  the gate when you want it to stay on. SCRs have some (uncharacterized) GTO (Gate Turn Off) action. Add a diode in series with the gate or move the resistor to the anode as Kevin suggests.,

First, you have another issue with your circuit, namely a resistor between +5 V supply and the base-collector joint of Q7 and Q10.
You could use a 10kΩ resistor there.
The second issue is the R23 value being too high, giving you less than 45 mA of current, while this SCR model needs at least 125 mA to latch (turn ON).
This SCR (thyristor) is too overpowered for your circuit: you don't need its 1200 V voltage rating, nor its high current rating - there are SCRs rated for less than 500 V, a gate trigger current less than 5 mA and a holding current of less than 25 mA.
Since SCR in your circuit needs to run a low current through your R23 discharge resistor, you can use some of the lowest power rated SCRs available, which would need a much lower gate current to switch ON, and a lower anode current to STAY ON.
Another downside of your circuit with this SCR is that even if the SCR latches ON and stays ON, it will ONLY stay ON until the current through the resistor goes below the SCR's "holding current", which will happen before the capacitor is discharged because this current depends on the capacitor voltage across the resistor (and SCR).

Below is a shot of your SCR's datasheet, with three notes to hep you understand the three of the basic ratings:

Gate Trigger Current - is the current that needs to be applied to the gate to trigger the SCR ON.
The important thing to remember is that this current is only needed to switch SCR ON, not to keep it ON, as long as the current through SCR's anode is above its "holding current" rating.
The gate switches the SCR ON within micro-seconds, definitely faster than 1 ms, so the gate trigger pulse can be very short.
"Latching Current" rating tells you the minimum anode current required to make the SCR latch ON, in other words to turn ON so that the gate current is no longer needed.
"Holding Current" is the minimum current needed to keep the SCR turned ON after it has latched ON, and is always smaller than the latching current.
This is similar to the way a relay or a solenoid works: it has a significantly higher voltage at which it switches ON (or engages), compared to the voltage at which it "releases" contacts (or disengages), for example a 12V-solenoid relay would turn on at about 9 to 10 volts, but release or turn off at about 5 to 7 volts.



The datasheet specs a Holding Current of 115 mA. With your 1k resistor R23, you only have at most 45 mA
.
Another issue with the circuit is that you should add a resistor between the collector of Q10 and the power supply. It needs to be small enough to provide sufficient base current to Q7 so that Q7 can give more than the 50 mA gate current for the SCR plus what flows through LED D3, but large enough so that whatever current flows through Q10 when illuminated can pull the base of Q7 down.
